# GIT post-receive hook doesn't run

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive

This has been asked a lot of times and I went through countless threads and Google pages, but none seem to be able to fix my issue. Perhaps I am not doing it the standard way, but it should still work.

I have a remote server that has a git repo

I push to it from local via ssh:

```
git add Y:\NetBeansProjects\pics\pics-client-branding\src\main\java\com\waudware\pics\viewer\TypeTopComponent.java
git commit -m Testing GIT Friday 8 Y:\NetBeansProjects\pics\pics-client-branding\src\main\java\com\waudware\pics\viewer\TypeTopComponent.java
Commit Log
revision   : b2d7fd5cbafbfddfccf8d3c8ac75614c4b357887
author     : Denis <Denis@WWOscar.Waudware.local>
date       : Jun 21, 2013 3:21:47 PM
summary    : Testing GIT Friday 8

INFO: End of Commit

==[IDE]== Jun 21, 2013 3:21:48 PM Committing... finished.
==[IDE]== Jun 21, 2013 3:21:52 PM Pushing
git push ssh://wwbert/cygdrive/d/Shared_Data/Development/dev_NetBeans/Projects/PICS.git +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
Remote Repository Updates
Branch : master
Old Id : e51af3dbc01ee2372f9c92bb8070cb1100bef220
New Id : b2d7fd5cbafbfddfccf8d3c8ac75614c4b357887
Result : OK

Local Repository Updates
Branch : origin/master
Old Id : e51af3dbc01ee2372f9c92bb8070cb1100bef220
New Id : b2d7fd5cbafbfddfccf8d3c8ac75614c4b357887
Result : FAST_FORWARD

==[IDE]== Jun 21, 2013 3:21:56 PM Pushing finished.
```

Pushing works fine and the remote repository gets updated. I can easily check that using putty and running `git show`. However, the post-receive hook that I wrote - doesn't run. The remote git project folder is: wwbert/cygdrive/d/Shared_Data/Development/dev_NetBeans/Projects/PICS.git and the hook is in wwbert/cygdrive/d/Shared_Data/Development/dev_NetBeans/Projects/PICS.git/hooks/post-receive

The contents of post-receive are:

```
#!bin/sh
touch worked.txt
SMTPSERVER=10.0.0.2
FROM=git-push-alert@waudware.com
TO=denis@waudware.com
SUBJECT="Subject: GIT [commit] $(date +"%m-%d-%Y")"
LOGFILE="commit-$(date +"%m-%d-%Y").log"
DIFF=1
SHORTLOG=1
echo "$SUBJECT" > ../logs/"$LOGFILE"
echo >> ../logs/"$LOGFILE"
git log --since=yesterday >> ../logs/"$LOGFILE"
if [ "$DIFF" == "1" ]; then
        git show --pretty >> ../logs/"$LOGFILE"
fi

git send-email --smtp-server "$SMTPSERVER" --to "$TO"  --from "$FROM" ../logs/"$LOGFILE"
```

I must note that executing that file manually sends the email as expected. But never triggers as a hook. Not even the `touch`. Any hints on what you think the cause of this may be is apprecaited!

P.S. `ls -la` on the hooks folder:

```
WAUDWARE\denis@WWBert /cygdrive/d/Shared_Data/Development/dev_NetBeans/Projects/pics.git/hooks
$ ls -la
total 38
drwxr-x--- 1 WAUDWARE\denis WAUDWARE\12513 4096 2013-06-21 15:20 .
drwxr-x--- 1 WAUDWARE\denis WAUDWARE\12513 4096 2013-06-21 14:48 ..
-rwxr-x--- 1 WAUDWARE\denis WAUDWARE\12513  452 2013-04-23 10:02 applypatch-msg.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 WAUDWARE\denis WAUDWARE\12513  896 2013-04-23 10:02 commit-msg.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 WAUDWARE\denis WAUDWARE\12513  160 2013-04-23 10:02 post-commit.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 WAUDWARE\denis WAUDWARE\12513  514 2013-06-21 16:08 post-receive
-rwxr-x--- 1 WAUDWARE\denis WAUDWARE\12513  552 2013-04-23 10:02 post-receive.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 WAUDWARE\denis WAUDWARE\12513  189 2013-04-23 10:02 post-update.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 WAUDWARE\denis WAUDWARE\12513  398 2013-04-23 10:02 pre-applypatch.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 WAUDWARE\denis WAUDWARE\12513 1578 2013-04-23 10:02 pre-commit.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 WAUDWARE\denis WAUDWARE\12513 4951 2013-04-23 10:02 pre-rebase.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 WAUDWARE\denis WAUDWARE\12513 1239 2013-04-23 10:02 prepare-commit-msg.sample
-rwxr-x--- 1 WAUDWARE\denis WAUDWARE\12513 3611 2013-04-23 10:02 update.sample
```

Edit: I had progress. Instead of pushing from NetBeans IDE, I used Git GUI to see a more detailed output. Here is what happened when I pushed to remote: `remote: fatal: cannot exec 'hooks/post-receive': Permission denied[K
To ssh://WAUDWARE\denis@wwbert/cygdrive/d/Shared_Data/Development/dev_NetBeans/Projects/PICS.git
   ab6ddef..a5644e8  master -> master`. You can see my permissions in the post. Is there anything wrong with them? Are there some other permissions that can prevent execution of post-receive?

Comment: Considering that hooks are executed on the root directory of the repo (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11655420/6309), are you sure you are looking for a '`worked.txt`' file in the right place, and that '`../logs`' refers to the right directory?

Comment: @VonC the post-receive is in the pics.git/hooks folder; however, the `touch worked.txt` doesn't seem to appear in either pics.git directory or pics.git/hooks/ =( The logs directory is in pics.git/logs/. From what you said, it seems that a post-receive will run as if from pics.git so I don't need to go up a level?

Comment: @VonC Just tried changing my `../logs/` to just `logs` as if it were to run from pics.git dir; however, still no luck. Script still works if executed as `sh hooks/post-receive`, but not when I push from local to remote :/

Comment: @VonC I had progress. Instead of pushing from NetBeans IDE, I used Git GUI to see a more detailed output. Here is what happened when I pushed to remote: `remote: fatal: cannot exec 'hooks/post-receive': Permission denied[K
To ssh://WAUDWARE\denis@wwbert/cygdrive/d/Shared_Data/Development/dev_NetBeans/Projects/PICS.git
   ab6ddef..a5644e8  master -> master`. You can see my permissions in the post. Is there anything wrong with them? Are there some other permissions that can prevent execution of post-receive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the leading / on the hash-bang (1st) line of your script.

Here's some other debugging tips:

Note that you can use $GIT_DIR to locate stuff relative to the repo.

Another idea is to turn on echo in the shell.

#!/bin/bash -x

Then the remote should show you exactly which line is causing you grief.

Finally, I think there's a problem with your nested quotes on the SUBJECT= line.
You could use single quotes for the inner quotes.  LOGFILE has the same problem.

Comment: I don't know what it was, but I added the leading / on the first line as well as -x and everything worked this morning. Permission error that I was getting last night seemed to have went away. And these debugging tips were quite great! I could see every line doing what it was supposed to! Thanks!